# Yii2 GridView column data display with comma separation format

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-dynagrid

I am using Kartik GridView in yii2 project.

When I specify column format as decimal it shows the output as 112,233,335.

I want this number as 11,22,33,335.

How can I do so ? I also want page summery for this column in the same comma separated format.

Comment: and your code? you can use yii2 [asDecimal()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDecimal()-detail)

Comment: you should use Masked-input, look at this:  http://demos.krajee.com/masked-input

Answer (score 0):

you can set it :

```
['format'=>'number', 'decimals'=>2, 'decPoint'=>'.', 'thousandSep'=>',']
```

change 2 to which you desire  .

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked for me:

```
        'pageSummaryFunc' => function ($data) { 
            array_walk($data, function (&$v) {
                $v = intval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $v));
            });
            return General::getInrFormat(array_sum($data));
        },
```

In this code I specify what to display and how to calculate page_summary for the column.
getInrFormat() is my own function which returns the numeric value in indian currency format.